# SQL Select Statement Complication

Tags: php, sql, ajax, database

I have two tables. One table has ID, Text. The other has ID, Username.

When someone logs into the page, they have a username id, so username has a value.

I want to select ID and TEXT from table 1, where ID matches ID in table two and the value of Username for that ID grabbed is same as the person logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `t1` and `t2` with your appropriate table names.  I'm not sure what language you're using for the code, but replace  with the value of the user that is logged in.

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.TEXT
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
WHERE t2.username = '<some username>'
```

After your comments, here's the new query:

```
$Query = "SELECT LandingPage_Notification.ID, LandingPage_Notification.Title, LandingPage_Notification.HTML,LandingPage_Notification.DateExpiry FROM LandingPage_Notification LEFT JOIN Track_Notification on Track_Notification.ID = LandingPage_Notification.ID WHERE Track_Notification.Track_UserID= '$userName'";
```

Comment: im writing in php, would this still be good

Comment: yes this will work for mysql.  Just replace <some username> with your $username variable.

Comment: Its not working still and Im not sure why.

Comment: $Query = "SELECT 
 LandingPage_Notification.ID, LandingPage_Notification.Title, LandingPage_Notification.HTML,LandingPage_Notification.DateExpiry
 FROM LandingPage_Notification
 LEFt JOIN Track_Notification on Track_Notification.ID
 WHERE Track_Notification.Track_UserID= '<$userName>'";

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` isn't including the `ON` clause.  So the query doesn't know how to join the two tables. I'll edit my answer.  Also you don't need the `<` and `>` in the query, I just put those there in my pseudocode as a placeholder for where `$userName` should be

Comment: I tried the edited code. But im still getting the error:

mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: The argument im supplying is $Query

Comment: Can you try running the sql directly in your database?  mysql_fetch_array might be having a problem with something else besides the query.

Comment: sorry, this function is the problem>>>>>>>>>> $result = mysql_query($Query) or die('Error');

Comment: I get an error from this function

Comment: Try running the query directly in your phpmyadmin, and see what error it gives you.

Comment: $Query = "SELECT LandingPage_Notification.ID, LandingPage_Notification.Title, LandingPage_Notification.HTML,LandingPage_Notification.DateExpiry FROM LandingPage_Notification LEFT JOIN Track_Notification on Track_Notification.ID = LandingPage_Notification.ID WHERE Track_Notification.Track_UserID= '$userName'";


MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$Query = "SELECT LandingPage_Notification.ID, LandingPage_Notification.Title, La' at line 1

Comment: You can't post the entire $Query = ".... into your phpmyadmin query window.  Replace $username with a sample username you're trying to query, then try running just this in phpmyadmin:  SELECT LandingPage_Notification.ID, LandingPage_Notification.Title, LandingPage_Notification.HTML,LandingPage_Notification.DateExpiry FROM LandingPage_Notification LEFT JOIN Track_Notification on Track_Notification.ID = LandingPage_Notification.ID WHERE Track_Notification.Track_UserID= 'Insert Username Here'

Comment: OKAY I GOT IT. ONE THING>> If i want to choose the id, html, title...where the id does not exist in table 2 with username in table 2, what would change?

Comment: Change the WHERE Clause to look for a NULL username:  `WHERE Track_Notification.Track_UserID IS NULL`

Comment: Awesome, Thanks a million for all the help

Comment: Be sure to mark as answer if you wouldn't mind.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Joins in SQL.

Something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT a.ID, a.TEXT FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id WHERE b.id = 'ID of person logged in';
```

Comment: So in this case, would 'a' be table1, or i would just write 'a'

Comment: @user3337821 You should look up "aliases". When you write "from table1 a", this makes "a" an alias for table1, so from then on you can use "a" instead of "table1". This can be handy when the table name is long. It is essential if you want to join a table to itself, as you then have to have a way to give different names to the two occurrences of the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pseudo query, but you might be able to paste it into your query editor to get results.

$Username is a variable presumably sent as a variable in the URL.

```
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM [Table 1] WHERE [ID]=(SELECT TOP 1 [ID] FROM [Table 2] WHERE Username='$Username')
```

You didn't specify a Database type, so remember to encapsulate your tables with the appropriate qualifiers. The above are good for SQLServer and Access, but you might need to use ` instead for MySQL.